# AWS: Beanstalk ERROR: Operation Denied. Are your permissions correct? with EB CLI

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli

Trying AWS hosting for the first time. Am using python3.4 eb CLI. Am always getting same Error output for eb init. On simulator for the same user all actions are allowed. Where am I going wrong? Why do I always get ERROR: Operation Denied. Are your permissions correct?

Used pip to install eb cli. Any pointers will be helpful.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This looks like the credentials you are using have limited permissions.

When you first setup the EB CLI, or run `aws configure`, you will be prompted for your AWS Access Key ID and AWS Secret Access Key. These are the credential keys for a specific root account or [IAM User](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/getting-started_create-admin-group.html). It is best practice to use an IAM User for most access.

If you have already setup your credentials for the CLI you can check them either in the `~/.aws/config` or `~/.aws/credentials` file.

An example of a `~/.aws/credentials` would be like so:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
aws_secret_access_key = wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY

[limited]
aws_access_key_id = AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
aws_secret_access_key = wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY
```

By default the credentials under the `[default]` option will be used if no profile is specified in the command line. If you wish to use a specific profile of credentials you can specify them like this: `eb init --profile limited`.

You can search for the credentials being used via the [IAM console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?region=us-east-1#/users), from there you can view which permissions have been granted to your user. You can also add permissions for that user in this console.