# AWS ERROR: EndpointConnectionError - Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://ec2.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to deploy my python application unto AWS Elastic Beanstalk.
I followed the instruction here
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html

I used eb init command and I have been able to

1. select the default region
2. enter an application to use
3. enter the type of language
4. setup the SSH
5. select the keypair
6. Then I was provided with the keypair name and the passphrase then it gave me the message `Uploaded SSH public key for`
7. Then entered the command `eb create django-env` even though it created a zip for me app-version.zip it brings out the error

When I used `eb create django-env`

```
 `ERROR: NotAuthorizedError - Operation Denied. Access Denied`
```

I used eb init -i to try to deploy my project again it gave me the same error.

Please what can be wrong

**Update**

there were no location where I was provided with access-key but what I was asked was keypair name and passphrase which does not exist in the credentials I downloaded

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS: Beanstalk ERROR: Operation Denied. Are your permissions correct? with EB CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28072430/aws-beanstalk-error-operation-denied-are-your-permissions-correct-with-eb-cl)

Comment: thank you for the response. that question was talking about access key but the one I am doing there were no access-key required what I was asked was `keypair name` and `passphrase`

Comment: I've tried following the aws-doc you wrote and django-env successfully 
 launched. Created keypair name `aws-eb` shown as default and empty passphrase. Is your keypair's region correct?Or there is something missing...

Comment: @shimo I am sorry I made a mistake it is actually an error coming from `eb create django-env`. it is the one giving  me those errors. But all through the process there were no location/prompt which asked for `aws-access-key` or `secret-access`

Comment: EB CLI configure might be fixed.

Comment: @shimo please can you shed more light on what you wrote

Comment: You seemingly opened another question on this topic. So I'm afraid please close this one.

Comment: @shimo Sorry, please pardon me, I am very sorry I do not intend to open many trends. I am looking for solution to a problem which is suspending all my work. Tht was why I made an update to the question I earlier asked. When I saw that it did not look clear that was why I opened another question to make it clearer. I am still open to your assistance and knowledge u wanted to share on the `eb cli` configuration it might be what i would need later (maybe in another project).